# Does Ruby ActiveRecord support time-to-live or record expiration?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Just an example to facilitate the question:

Assume I have a class Authorizations which has thousands of persistant records, but I also want to assert numerous non-persistent records.  In other words, I want to derive additional Authorizations, but I am concerned the derived authorizations will be subject to changing conditions so I only want that authorization to 'live' for a short period of time; 5 minutes or an hour.

I have searched the Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord documentation and Googled 'Ruby ActiveRecord time to live' and 'Ruby ActiveRecord record expire'.

One consideration is to have a different class AuthorizationCache associated with an in-memory ActiveRecord while Authorization class is associated with my database server.  But, that would require my code to first look at the AuthorizationCache then Authorization and I'm sure that would make me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use expired_at field in your model with the expiration time for short-lived authorizations and nil or very big values for long-lived ones?

To destroy expired authorizations every hour/day/month you can use periodical task.